# How can i rearrange a php array without using key names

Tags: php, arrays

My array is below i need to arrange like array2 (without use $aa['caption1'] like names directly)
**arrray1 is**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [caption1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => gfdhgfjhg
                    [1] => dfhfgjghk
                )

            [caption2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => shgjgh
                    [1] => dhfgkgjl
                )

            [banner_image] => Array
                (
                    [0] => assets/images/page_content/img_namT7.jpg
                    [1] => assets/images/page_content/img_R8mzP.jpg
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [heading] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 
                )

            [pragraph] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 
                )

        )
)
```

**arrray2 is(Required format )**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
          array('caption1'=>'caption1','caption2'=>'shgjgh','banner_image'=>'assets/images/page_content/img_namT7.jpg'),
          array('caption1'=>'dfhfgjghk','caption2'=>'dhfgkgjl','banner_image'=>'page_content/img_R8mzP.jpg')           
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
           array('heading'=>'','pragraph'=>''),
           array('heading'=>'fgh','pragraph'=>'ghgh'),
        )
)
```

please any one help me.

Comment: note, there's no such record `'heading'=>'fgh','pragraph'=>'ghgh'` within intial array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution using `array_keys`, `array_map` and `array_combine` functions:

```
// $arr is your initial array
$result = [];
foreach($arr as $v){
    $keys = array_keys($v);
    $data = call_user_func_array('array_map', [null] + $v);
    $result[] = array_map(function($item) use($keys){ 
        return array_combine($keys, $item); 
    }, $data);
}

print_r($result);
```

The output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [caption1] => gfdhgfjhg
                    [caption2] => shgjgh
                    [banner_image] => assets/images/page_content/img_namT7.jpg
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [caption1] => dfhfgjghk
                    [caption2] => dhfgkgjl
                    [banner_image] => assets/images/page_content/img_R8mzP.jpg
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [heading] => 
                    [pragraph] => 
                )
        )
)
```